# height 100% understanding how to use it

Tags: html, css, height

Ok really simple question, I want to make a section 100% height of the viewport, I understand that the parent element needs to have a defined height but it still doesn't work for me. Help me understand if I'm overlooking something!

```
html { 
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
} 

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SzBM5/

Comment: Oh there's always one sarcastic comment, unfortunately DevTools don't give you an explanation.

Comment: Hovering over the body element and seeing it has the height of the content would be an explanation to some of us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `html, body{ height: 100%; }`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SzBM5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height 100% at the BODY and the HTML.

```
body, html {
   height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pGa6t/

Answer (score 0):

Your need to set `height:100%` for `body` also.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNuQL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use This Css **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/yhBTP/)**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:100%;
} 

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:red;
}
```